# how can i display heading inside navbar?

Tags: html, css

```
        .navbar {
            background-color: #EB0E58;
            width: 1660px;
            height: 10px;
            border: 5px solid blue;
            padding: 10px;
            position: fixed;
            left: 0;
            top: 0;
```

```
 <div class="navbar"> <h2>Home</h2></div>
```

How can i display Home Heading inside Navigation Bar?
Thank You
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XO8GI.png)

i think it should be in navbar

Comment: remove all your css code and it will work fine, why are you using position fixed in your css code?

Comment: I want to make the navbar stuck on top and left, if i don't use position fixed its gonna down below.

Comment: remove height: 10px from your css code and it will work fine. setting height 10px limit its size so dont do it

Answer (score 0):

remove the height and the css code will be like this,

```
.navbar {
        background-color: #EB0E58;
        width: 1660px;
        border: 5px solid blue;
        padding: 10px;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
}
```

the result in jsbin
[image]